# How can I use foreign keys for an array or list of relations?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

First of all, I have to admit, that I'm totally inexperienced in using SQL databases, so I might be wrong in my assumption, that it's possible to achieve what I'd like to do.

I have the following minimal Room setup where a `Thing` should contain multiple `Item`s:

```
// item.java

@Entity(table_name = "items")
public class Item {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
}


// thing.java

@Entity(tableName = "things",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Item.class,
                                  parentColumns = "id",
                                  childColumns = "item_ids"));
public class Thing {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_ids")
    public List<Integer> itemIds; // this is a list of references to Items
}
```

Would this code work like expected? And if not, is there a better solution?

Comment: what error are you running into with this?

Comment: Unfortunately my project currently is in an early stage, where it's not easily testable. If you think that it would work like written above, I will create a little test project to try it. But for me the solution looked too simple.